# Warning: Division by zero in /home/

Tags: php, mysql

I've search for the issue, but cant find it, I have a script that gives me this warning Warning: Division by zero in /home/ on line 52.php - you can see the error on http://usedcarsforsaleingauteng.com/

If you look below, $pages  = ceil($total / $_GET[p]); // number of pages is line 52.php

Can you guys help please. Thank you

```
// get total number of entries for pagenation
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $dblist $where", $link);
$total  = mysql_fetch_array($result); $total = $total[0]; // total number of listings
$pages  = ceil($total / $_GET[p]); // number of pages
}
```

Comment: the `GET` parameter `p` is unset. What does your URL look like when accessing the page?

Comment: `$_GET['p']` will not be defined unless there's an argument called `p` in the query string... so you need to have a default page length in case it's not set.

Comment: Not meaning to be obvious ... but have you checked to make sure that "$_GET[p]" has been assigned a nonzero value ;)?  And what's "p"?  I think you probably need something like this: if (isset($_GET['p'])) { $pages = = ceil($total / $_GET['p']);...`

Comment: Also check if the 'p' constant is defined and what is the value if it is.

Comment: I should probably say Im not a coder, but I have full access, know html and css and some php, and can follow clear instructions ;-)

Comment: Okay, the issue was not there, until I renamed the folder /admin to something else and a few files require that /folders files, but I quickly changed it back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$_GET['p']` not `$_GET[p]`  (notice the ' )

I just checked out your website and saw the error. You are not setting the `$_GET['p']` variable to a fallback value if it isn't supplied with the url.

When you visit http://usedcarsforsaleingauteng.com/ you see the error, but not with : http://usedcarsforsaleingauteng.com/?p=1

You should have a fallback value:

```
if($_GET['p']){
 $page = $_GET['p'];
} else{
 $page = 1;
}
$pages  = ceil($total / $page);
```

Comment: Well then probably the $_GET['p'] is not set or it's value is 0. try printing it.

Comment: Okay, the issue was not there, until I renamed the folder /admin to something else and a few files require that /folders files, but I quickly changed it back

Comment: Updated the answer, it should fix your problem

Comment: Okay, I'll try this quickly thansk

Comment: That did sort out the problem but I see this issue on may other pages now too, it probably was there before :-(

Answer (score 2):

The best way round this would be to check if `$_GET['p']` is 0 before you do the division, something like;

```
$pages = ($_GET['p']==0) ? 1 : ceil($total / $_GET['p']);
```

Or whatever you want `$pages` to be if `$_GET['p']` is 0 (I've just assumed 1 in the above example)

Answer (score 1):

`$_GET[p]` is probably undefined. You should check if it exists:

```
if(isset($_GET['p'])) {
    $p = (int) $_GET['p'];
    // Your code
    if($p != 0)
        $pages  = ceil($total / $p);
    else {
        // Do errorhandling e.g. setting $page = 0
    }
}
```

Also note that you should always write `$_GET['p']` instead of `$_GET[p]`.